# Как получить usernam пользователя который присоединился к боту?

Tags: telegram, telebot, бот

Мне нужно получить в базу данных username пользователя ,который присоединился к моему боту.
Использую PyTelegramBotApi,база данных MySQL
Для получения username использую команду message.from_user.username
В файле базы данных делаю вот так

```
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`username` ) VALUES (?,?)", (message.from_user.username))
```

В итоге ничего не получается

Answer (score 0):

Вы говорите вставить одно значение, а вписали два плейсхолдера

> "INSERT INTO `users` (`username` ) VALUES (?**,?**)"

Comment: Users это название таблицы ,а username название столбца

Comment: еще раз. речь о плейсхолдерах. в вашем случае VALUES(?) поскольку значение только одно - username

Comment: Это я исправил,все равно ничего не получилось, я думаю проблема в команде message.from_user.username нужно что-то добавить,но не знаю что